# Asterisk- How to 'whisper' music using ChanSpy(), or any alternative?

Tags: asterisk, playback, conference

I intend to 'whisper' music/message file to one of the conference participants without making this message audible to other conference participants. I went through Audio Manipulation chapter in Asterisk Cookbook 
(http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449303822/c03-AudioManipulation_id302347.html )
but couldn't figure out:

1) How to implement 'whisper' music file to a participant of conference using ChanSpy?

2) Is 'whisper'ing the music file using ChanSpy the best approach? Would you recommend, getting the user out of conference playing the message, and putting her back into the conference?

I would greatly appreciate your responses. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question of best approach depends on what exactly your trying to do. You only specified that you want to whisper music/message to a single participent. Removing them from the conference for that will only be MORE complicated. As far as how to, here is approximate code:

Dialplan:

```
[whisper-to-participant]
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,ChanSpy(<Participants channel>,w)
```

Then originate a call (in this example were using a call file, although AMI would work just fine) as:

```
Channel: Local/s@whisper-to-participant
Application: Playback
Data: <prompt/music file>
```

While my syntax may not be perfect here, this is the basic idea of how to stream/whisper data to a single participant.

Comment: I've been trying similar things but somehow it didnt work. Will update the post if I figure it out, but for now I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Thanks! Again, remember my code is pseudo-code, not compiler-happy code!

Comment: I completely realize that it is a pseudo-code and not the final code.

Comment: BTW, I've posted a related question, please see if you have any suggestion/comment on it--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662846/are-there-parallels-to-asterisk-ami-and-agi-in-freeswitch

Comment: is it possible to detect talk on both ends? the channel which is dailed and the channel who dails? right now i am only able to detect it on the channel who dails..but i need to detect it on both channels?