# play beep in asterisk confbridge in a specific time to all callers

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am making a conference using asterisk conference for a group of users.

First of all, i am using call file to call the users. When they accept the call, they are put to a conference using asterisk conf bridge. Now i need to play a beep at a specific time interval after conference has been started/user has been entered to the conference. This beep should be played to all users at a time.

**Is there any method to play the beep in call file or AMI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was successfull to play beep using chanspy.

Check this link:

[Asterisk- How to 'whisper' music using ChanSpy(), or any alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099018/asterisk-how-to-whisper-music-using-chanspy-or-any-alternative#answer-8604223)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create call to conference via Local channel and playback beep.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Call+Files

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+local+channels